# Filter path arrays to leave only root folders (c#)

Tags: c#

I have a path array like this:

```
var sample = new string[]
        {
          @"C:\Eclipse", @"C:\Eclipse\eclipse", @"C:\Eclipse\SDK",
          @"C:\Program Files", @"C:\Program Files\cheese", @"C:\Program Files\bool\de",
          @"D:\bananas", @"D:\", @"F:\cupoftea", @"F:\cupoftea\soup", @"C:\Eclipse\Random", @"C:\this\is\a\very\long\path", @"C:\this\is\a",@"C:\this\is\a\very",@"E:\Stuff\can\be\levels\and\levels\deep@",@"E:\Stuff\can\be\levels"
        };
```

How can i receive the following output:

```
var filteredResult = new string[]
         { 
           @"C:\Eclipse",
           @"C:\Program Files",
           @"D:\",
           @"F:\cupoftea",
           @"C:\this\is\a",
           @"E:\Stuff\can\be\levels"
         }
```

UPDATE: I guess i have written the question somewhat poorly - updated the examples. The idea is to abstract of levels, but not take anything that is a child of anything else in the array.

What i've tried:

```
Array.Sort(sample);
  Array.Reverse(sample);
  List<string> filteredResult = new List<string>();
  foreach (var s in sample)
  {
    List<string> x = sample.ToList();
    x.Remove(s);
    if (!x.Any(xx => xx.StartsWith(s)))
    {
      filteredResult .Add(s);
    }
  }
```

However, it contains:

```
F:\cupoftea\soup
E:\Stuff\can\be\levels\and\levels\deep@
D:\bananas
C:\this\is\a\very\long\path
C:\Program Files\cheese
C:\Program Files\bool\de
C:\Eclipse\SDK
C:\Eclipse\Random
C:\Eclipse\eclipse
```

**UPDATE**
Although i accepted a great solution from Muctadir, i have discovered doing some testing today that it fails when the folder names are iterative, e.g. `@"C:\Bananas\folder1",@"C:\Bananas\folder10",@"C:\Bananas\folder100",@"C:\Bananas\folder1000",@"C:\Bananas\folder1001"`

The code would filter these out as they satisfy the `.StartsWith()` condition.
Since i control the trailing `\` symbols, i worked around this like so (also adding another IsAlone method to handle the case where only one folder begins with a given path):

```
private static bool HasChildDirectory(string s, string[] sample)
{
  var hasChildDirectory = sample.Any(p => p.Substring(0, p.LastIndexOf(@"\", StringComparison.Ordinal)).StartsWith(s) && p != s);
  return hasChildDirectory;
}

private static bool IsChildDirectory(string s, string[] sample)
{
  var isChildDirectory = sample.Any(p => s.Substring(0, s.LastIndexOf(@"\", StringComparison.Ordinal)).StartsWith(p) && p != s);
  return isChildDirectory;
}

private static bool IsAlone(string s, string[] sample)
{
  var isAlone = !sample.Any(p => p.Substring(0, p.LastIndexOf(@"\", StringComparison.Ordinal))
 != s.Substring(0, s.LastIndexOf(@"\", StringComparison.Ordinal)) 
  && p.Substring(0, p.LastIndexOf(@"\", System.StringComparison.Ordinal))
  .Contains(s.Substring(0, s.LastIndexOf(@"\", StringComparison.Ordinal))));

return isAlone;
}

var enumerable = sample.Where(s => !IsChildDirectory(s, sample) && (HasChildDirectory(s, sample) || IsAlone(s, sample)));
```

I suppose for arrays with both absent and present trailing \ symbols it is possible to first normalise endings.

Comment: By working a bit on it? :) Please, can you show us what you have done so far?

Comment: @L.B D:\bananas is not included because we have D:\ in array. Also, the result doesnt have both eclipse\eclipse. It only has the one which is closer to the root.

Comment: this question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep only those having depth 2

```
    IEnumerable<string> enumerable = sample.Where(s => s.Split('\\').Count() <= 2);
```

To extract paths to depth 2

```
    IEnumerable<string> enumerable = sample.Select(s => string.Join("\\", s.Split('\\').Take(2))).Distinct();
```

**Update**

Solution for updated question

```
    var enumerable = sample.Where(s => !IsChildDirectory(s, sample) && HasChildDirectory(s, sample));

    private bool HasChildDirectory(string s, string[] sample)
    {
        var hasChildDirectory = sample.Any(p => p.StartsWith(s) && p != s);
        return hasChildDirectory;
    }

    private bool IsChildDirectory(string s, string[] sample)
    {
        var isChildDirectory = sample.Any(p => s.StartsWith(p) && p != s);
        return isChildDirectory;
    }
```

Comment: that's great, except i guess my question was poorly written. that sample can have 20 level folders, i want to only get the rootmost ones..

Comment: it still is not clear for me. care to explain a little bit more?

Comment: very keen so - updated payloads in the post. I want to get the folders that have no subfolders anywhere in this array. So if i give a c: drive, and a c:\documents and settings, i expect only c: back (which is easy). But i also expect to have all sorts of levels and drive letters in this array in any random order (so i can't, for instance, order by length and go from there).

Comment: you're just wow with linq. However, this still contains an extra result, and D:\ is gone somewhere: 
C:\Eclipse
C:\Program Files
D:\
F:\cupoftea
C:\this\is\a
C:\this\is\a\very
E:\Stuff\can\be\levels

Comment: Actually, D:\ is there, so its just those duplicate C records... weird.

Comment: Wow. Just wow. If you ever move to Australia i can always give you a reference. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: just as an FYI, check out an update, there is an unhandled scenario in your code that i worked around.

Answer (score 0):

Here how you  can achieve this

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var sample = new string[]
        {
          @"C:\Eclipse", @"C:\Eclipse\eclipse", @"C:\Eclipse\SDK",
          @"C:\Program Files", @"C:\Program Files\cheese", @"C:\Program Files\bool\de",
          @"D:\bananas", @"D:\", @"F:\cupoftea", @"F:\cupoftea\soup", @"C:\Eclipse\Random"
        };
          var res =   sample.Select(s =>
              {
                  string news;
                    if (s.LastIndexOf("\\")>2)
                    {
                        news = s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf(@"\",3));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        news = s.Substring(0, s.LastIndexOf(@"\"));
                    }
                    return news;
                }).Distinct();
            //write all strings
            foreach (var re in res)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(re);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: This is the result i got... :
C:
C:\Eclipse
C:\Eclipse
C:
C:\Program Files
C:\Program Files
D:
D:
F:
F:\cupoftea
C:\Eclipse

Comment: so you  don't want the duplication  or what

Comment: This had more items than the originally expected result payload?

Comment: take a look  now it should be ok

Comment: it works up to level 2, unfortunately my paths can be any (unknown) levels deep.

Comment: no  it works for any level @"C:\Program Files\bool\de"

Comment: when i run the code you wrote against the updated payload, i get back: C:
C:\Eclipse
C:\Program Files
D:
F:
F:\cupoftea
C:\this
E:\Stuff